# How do I flip an enemy moving along patrol points in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I realize this is a common question, but I am new to coding and Unity, and all my "solutions" have failed. The enemy moves along random patrol points on the 2D map, but it isn't symmetrical and I would like it to flip on the x axis every time it moves in that direction

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PatrolBehavior : StateMachineBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] patrolPoints;
    public float speed;
    private int randomPoint;
    // OnStateEnter is called when a transition starts and the state machine starts to evaluate this state
    override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        patrolPoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("patrolPoints");
        randomPoint = Random.Range(0, patrolPoints.Length);

    }

    // OnStateUpdate is called on each Update frame between OnStateEnter and OnStateExit callbacks
    override public void OnStateUpdate(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        animator.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(animator.transform.position, patrolPoints[randomPoint].transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (Vector2.Distance(animator.transform.position, patrolPoints[randomPoint].transform.position) < 0.1f)
        {
            randomPoint = Random.Range(0, patrolPoints.Length);
        }
    }

    // OnStateExit is called when a transition ends and the state machine finishes evaluating this state
    override public void OnStateExit(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        
    }


}
```

Before you ask about the code, it is not mine. I am following a tutorial for 99% of it, hence why I am useless when it comes to code problem solving. I would really appreciate a more tailored response rather
than " use animator.transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0);" because I don't know how to use that :(.

Answer (score 0):

To flip a sprite on the X axis:
SpriteRenderer renderer = GetComponent();
renderer.flipX = !renderer.flipX;

Answer (score 0):

You can flip via. LocalScale

**LocalScale Code Example:**

```cs
public void FlipSprite() {
    // Get the X Value of the patrolPoint
    float pointXValue = patrolPoints[randomPoint].transform.position.x;

    // Get the X Value of the Enemy
    float enemyXValue = gameObject.transform.x

    // PatrolPoint is to the Left
    if (pointXValue < enemyXValue) {
        // Flip Sprite on the X Axis
        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1f, 1f, 1f);
    }
    // PatrolPoint is to the Right
    else if (pointXValue > enemyXValue) {
        // Flip Sprite back on the X Axis
        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1f, 1f, 1f);
    }
}
```

That piece of code would need to be in the `GameObject` you want to flip, to access it's `Transform`, after you've choosen the new RandomRange Point. You would need to call the Function after each time you are setting the randomPoint.

```cs
// Getting new patrolPoint
randomPoint = Random.Range(0, patrolPoints.Length);
// Fliping Sprite
FlipSprite();
```

I would not advice you to flip via `flipX`. Only the `Rendering` (Sprite) is affected by the flipping. Everything else would stay the same, so if your `Collider2D` is not symmetrical it could lead to problems with the `Collisions` later on.